# How to append logs to STDOUT in WSO2?

Tags: wso2, log4j2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have a requirement where I want to publish the WSO2 API Manager(3.1.0) and Identity server(IS-KM - 5.1.0) logs to STDOUT. Can someone let me know how to configure it in log4j2.properties file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, WSO2 has a log appender named `CARBON_CONSOLE` which appends all the logs to stdout (Console) and you don't want to specifically use stdout (log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender) property to pipe logs to standard output